# Can't find output file/folder of papermill operator. Apache Airflow 2.0. Suppose to be in tmp folder. Output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, airflow, filepath, papermill

Can't find output file/folder of papermill operator. Apache Airflow 2.0. Suppose to be in tmp folder. Output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb" I am not able to find the file or folder anywhere.

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='fahar_papermill_operator_2',
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
) as dag_2:

run_this = PapermillOperator(
    task_id="run_example_notebook",
    input_nb=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 
    "count_20.ipynb"),
    output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb", 
    parameters={"msgs": "Ran from Airflow at {{ execution_date }}!"},
)
```

Comment: Are you running Airflow in a Docker container ?

Comment: Yes I am running in a Docker container.

Comment: Well then I suppose you should have a look at the folder inside your container, and not on your local machine ?

Comment: I checked all the folders, but couldn't find any temp folder. Do I need to create a temp folder? If yes then where should i create it. Following is my folder structure:

Under: aws-mwaa-local-runner
  -dags
  -docker
  -plugins